# C asks an input array of string until it is within a specified length

Tags: arrays, c, string, loops

I'm trying to make a code in C where in I'm asking the user to input an array of string, and if their input exceeds the length of 10 then I'm gonna print an error, and then loop back and ask again until they input a string that's lower than 10

What I did was make an 11 digit array, and then an endless for loop, and then make an if statement stating that if the 11th digit is no longer == '/0' then I'll print "error" then made an else as break.

Code:

```c
char x[11];

int main(void) {
    for (;;) {

        printf("Enter String X: ");
        scanf("%s", x);

        if (x[10] != '\0') {
            printf("ERROR\n");
        } else {

            break;
        }
    }

    return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

Which works for the most part if I enter equal to or less than 10 digits of strings it works, and if I enter more than 10 then it works as well prompting "ERROR" and asking to input the strings once more,

But the problem is that when I enter more than 10 to prompt the "ERROR", and then enter within the accepted length it will still give me "ERROR" unless i enter the exact length of 10 where it will work

Comment: Hint: `strlen(x) > 0`

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are new to C, when getting string input, the array is assigned with the characters inputted until the length of the input, and following a NULL value (`'\0'`).

You are checking if the last value is NULL, which is probably also the initial value of the array you allocated.

So once you have input `"1234567890A"`, `x[10] = 'A'`.
Now let's enter `"123"`, now: `x = "123\0567890A"`, and still `x[10] = 'A'`.

You need to use C's standard `strlen`, `strlen("123\0567890A") -> 3`.